# Задача на прологе

Tags: prolog

Укажите результат выполнения следующего запроса на Прологе:

```
-? author(X, Y), derivedFrom(Y, unix)
для программы:

author(dijkstra, algol).
author(ritchie, unix).
author(wirth, pascal).
author(kernighan, awk).
author(backus, fortran).
author(kernighan, unix) .
author(backus, algol) .
author(kernighan, awk).
author(ritchie, plan9).
author(ritchie, c).
author(torvalds, linux).
author(corbato, multics).
author(aho, awk).
author(thompson, c).
author(straustrup, cpp).
author(hubbard, freebsd).

basedOn(linux, unix).
basedOn(pascal, algol).
basedOn(plan9, unix).
basedOn(unix, multics).
basedOn(awk, c).
basedOn(inferno, plan9).
basedOn(limbo, c).
basedOn(cpp, c).
basedOn(freebsd, c).
basedOn(openbsd, freebsd).

derivedFrom(X, Y) :- basedOn(X, Y).
derivedFrom(X, Z) :- basedOn(X, Y), basedOn(Y, Z).
```

Comment: @Semen  Savenko, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А вопрос хорош. И главное -- ответить несложно. Только запустить какой-нибудь из прологов.

@KoVadim Вы справились отлично! :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

подойдет два варианта:

```
X = ritchie Y = plan9

X = torvalds Y =  linux
```

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/bEDqIT